# Query and list admin levels - join two tables

Tags: php, mysql

I want to creat a admin group which can access data by this level table,
the low level can't see the higher level's data.

0  =>　  **3**
high => **low**

User Table:

```
---------------------
uid  gid  uname 
---------------------
110   4   Jacky       =>means {gname: art_admin  ,level: 2}
111   1   Niky        =>means {gname: site_admin ,level: 0}
112   4   Cupe        =>means {gname: art_admin  ,level: 2}
113   2   Nancy       =>means {gname: gen_admin  ,level: 1}
113   5   Joe         =>means {gname: admin      ,level: 3}
```

Group Table:

```
---------------------
gid     gname       level
---------------------
1    site_admin    0 
2    gen_admin     1 
3    sys_admin     1
4    art_admin     2
5    admin         3
```

It means Jacky is belong to 'art_admin', and he's level is '2'.
so when he view the all user table, it just show the level under 2.

1. Jacky can see:**< Jacky , Cupe, Joe>** ,
2. Niky is the higher, so he can see all users:**< Jacky,Niky,Cupe,Nancy,Joe >**,
3. Joe is the lower, so she just can see herself: **< Joe >**

And then, how can I query it? Thanks.

**Pseudo code**

```
$uid = 110 ;// Assume I'm Jacky
$result = mysql_query("
    SELECT
        user.uname from user
    WHERE
        [ group.level >= Jacky's level ]   
";);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
   echo $row['uname']." , ";
}
```

It should return

```
 Jacky , Cupe , Joe
```

Comment: mysql_* is deprecated, use mysqli_* or PDO

Comment: Thanks, I am try to use PDO rightnow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this the query you are looking for?

```
select u.uname
from user u join
     groups g
     on u.gid = g.gid
where g.level >= (select g2.level
                  from user u2 join
                       groups g2
                       on u2.gid = g2.gid
                  where u2.uname = 'Jacky'
                 );
```